# Finding the equation of the circle given two points and a line passing through the center using the Perpendicular Bisector Theorem

Tags: geometry, circles

So this is the problem:

> Determine the equation of the circle passing through $(4,0)$ and $(3,5)$ with a line $3x+2y-7=0$ passing through the center.

I know the easier solution of this, but my teacher wants us to solve using our knowledge in Perpendicular Bisector Theorem. So can anyone help me?

Comment: the center of the circle is the intersection between the given line and the perpendicular bisector of the given points

Comment: So, what do you know of the Perpendicular Bisector Theorem?

Comment: @jmmp Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The center has coordinates

- $C=(t,(7-3t)/2)$

from the condition

$$d^2(CA)=d^2(CB) \implies (t-4)^2+\left(\frac{7-3t}{2}-0\right)^2=(t-3)^2+\left(\frac{7-3t}{2}-5\right)^2$$

we can find $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The chord of the circle connecting $(4,0)$ and $(3,5)$ has slope $-5$.
The perpendicular bisector of the chord will be a radius: this line passes through the mid-point of chord, $(7/2, 5/2)$ and has slope $1/5$. Its intersection with $3x+2y-7=0$ will be the centre of the circle.